# how to fix "Host www.saraframework.com not found" during compiling a scala project with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to compile a scala project from terminal on mac. 
the project was started in 2013

I have installed java sdk 7 and sbt 1.1.1 with homebrew

when I run command

```
sbt
```

from the project root folder i get following errors and warnings.

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/Sarfaraz/work/projects/git_repos/abc/scala_project/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/Sarfaraz/work/projects/git_repos/abc/scala_project/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/Sarfaraz/work/projects/git_repos/abc/scala_project/project/}default-085b3b...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.0.0 ...
[warn] Host www.saraframework.com not found. url=http://www.saraframework.com/artifactory/ivy/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-scalariform/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.0.0
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-scalariform/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-scalariform/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/Sarfaraz/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-scalariform/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-scalariform/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Sara Ivy: tried
[warn]   http://www.saraframework.com/artifactory/ivy/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-scalariform/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-scalariform_2.9.2_0.12/1.0.0/sbt-scalariform-1.0.0.pom
[info] Resolving com.sara.sbt#web-service;1.0.4 ...
[warn] Host www.saraframework.com not found. url=http://www.saraframework.com/artifactory/ivy/com.sara.sbt/web-service/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[warn]  module not found: com.sara.sbt#web-service;1.0.4
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.sara.sbt/web-service/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.sara.sbt/web-service/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/Sarfaraz/.ivy2/local/com.sara.sbt/web-service/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/com.sara.sbt/web-service/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Sara Ivy: tried
[warn]   http://www.saraframework.com/artifactory/ivy/com.sara.sbt/web-service/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sara/sbt/web-service_2.9.2_0.12/1.0.4/web-service-1.0.4.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_1;0.12.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.0.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.sara.sbt#web-service;1.0.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-scalariform:1.0.0 (sbtVersion=0.12, scalaVersion=2.9.2)
[warn]      com.sara.sbt:web-service:1.0.4 (sbtVersion=0.12, scalaVersion=2.9.2)
[warn] 
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.0.0: not found
unresolved dependency: com.sara.sbt#web-service;1.0.4: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:214)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:117)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:117)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:105)
    at sbt.IvySbt.liftedTree1$1(Ivy.scala:52)
    at sbt.IvySbt.action$1(Ivy.scala:52)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:61)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:61)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:102)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:117)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:955)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:953)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$58.apply(Defaults.scala:976)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$58.apply(Defaults.scala:974)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:978)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:973)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:981)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$47.apply(Defaults.scala:858)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$47.apply(Defaults.scala:855)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.0.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.sara.sbt#web-service;1.0.4: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

plugin.sbt file is like this

```
scalacOptions += "-deprecation"

credentials ++= Seq(
    Credentials("Sara Server", "www.saraframework.com", "saradeveloper", "teamkp"))

resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-snapshots",
  new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/"))(
    Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.url("Sara Ivy", url("http://www.saraframework.com/artifactory/ivy"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.sara.sbt" % "web-service" % "1.0.4")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.2")

addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.3")
```

and build.sbt file is

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform.{ScalariformKeys, scalariformSettings}
import scalariform.formatter.preferences._
import com.sara.sbt.common.Dependencies._
import net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings

webServiceSettings

net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings

name := "project"

version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

scalacOptions += "-language:postfixOps"

ivyXML := <dependencies>
  <exclude module="slf4j-log4j12"/>
  <exclude module="grizzled-slf4j_2.9.1"/>
  <exclude module="jsr311-api" />
</dependencies>

scalariformSettings

libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.24"

libraryDependencies += "com.sara" % "social-data_2.10" % "0.0.7"

libraryDependencies += "com.sara" % "aws-utils_2.10" % "0.0.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.sara" % "messaging_2.10" % "0.0.4"

libraryDependencies += "com.sara" % "persistence_2.10" % "0.0.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalastic" %% "scalastic" % "0.90.10.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.1.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.paypal.sdk" % "rest-api-sdk" % "0.7.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.9" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "fluent-hc" % "4.3.5"


ScalariformKeys.preferences :=
  (FormattingPreferences()
    setPreference(IndentSpaces, 2)
    setPreference(AlignParameters, false)
    setPreference(AlignSingleLineCaseStatements, true)
    setPreference(DoubleIndentClassDeclaration, true)
    setPreference(RewriteArrowSymbols, true)
    setPreference(PreserveSpaceBeforeArguments, true)
    setPreference(IndentWithTabs, false))

(excludeFilter in ScalariformKeys.format) <<= excludeFilter(_ || "*Spec.scala" || "*Test.scala" || "*Specification.scala")

// port in container.Configuration := 8080
```

this build setup was written in 2013 so i guess www.saraframework.com is closed and not working anymore. I have searched on the web for alternate urls but can't understand why there is nothing about this on the web.

I don't have much idea about what should I try at this stage, so it would be great if someone can point me in right direction or ask questions in comments which can lead to better understanding of the situation

Comment: Remove the resolver. But then you don't know where to find `com.sara.sbt`. And since it's not on maven central https://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|com.sara.sbt you might be screwed.

Answer (score 2):

- Check proxy your settings. Your `sbt` says `[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.`
- Check if a simple project builds. Try to add one and one dependency, build until it fails. Investigate that particular dependency.
- Check all dependencies. A dependency that is hosted on `Maven Central`, for example, should be listed on https://search.maven.org/
- If you can, host a minimal project (on GitHub, for example) which has your error.

Comment: Thanks for a very nice strategy. I created this project for tests. https://github.com/Sarfarazsajjad/scalatestproj .